# How to play an audio file from app folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

My app has only a button to play an audio file from my phone. Very simple app but I cannot achieve it works.

I added permission to manifest, and the app ask to accept it, but it doesn´t work anyway. I press the button and it does nothing. I know it is very simple but I really cannot find the mistake. I would thank any hint or help. Thanks in advance.

This is the MainActivity:

```
package com.doctoractual.playaudiofile;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnPlay;

    int REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

        checkPerm();
        reproducirAudio();
    }

    public void reproducirAudio(){

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String rutaArchivo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.doctoractual.savetts/files/0.wav";
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(rutaArchivo);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkPerm(){
        int permRead = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permRead == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso concedido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the logcat:

```
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1113)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1059)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at com.doctoractual.playaudiofile.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22641)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.236 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.237 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.237 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.237 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
2021-06-18 18:45:04.237 5560-5560/com.doctoractual.playaudiofile W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 //String rutaArchivo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.doctoractual.savetts/files/0.wav";
```

to

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.doctoractual.savetts/files/0.wav");
```

or

create `raw` folder in src , copy & paste audio file in `raw` folder

and follow this

```
btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.YOURAUDIO);
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
//this is very simple
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The point of this app is that you cannot copy the file to other folders. The file must be played from that folder "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.doctoractual.savetts/files/"

Comment: I am sure. I even tried to play a file from "/mnt/sdcard/download/", so that the path is easier, but I get the same error "W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed."

Comment: try this ```mediaPlayer.setDataSource(/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.doctoractual.savetts/files/0.wav");```

Comment: Same error message. I am trying different ways to write the path and trying different folders and files, but always the same result.

Comment: check this out , https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273577/12709358

Comment: I have checked it, but I don´t know how to apply it to my code

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved that it works.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnPlay;

    int REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

        checkPerm();
        pressButton();
    }

    public void pressButton(){

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                playfile();
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkPerm(){
        int permRead = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permRead == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso concedido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    private void playfile(){
        String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/android/data/com.doctoractual.savetts/files/0.wav";

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try { mp.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(filename)); } catch (Exception e) {}
        try { mp.prepare(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        mp.start();
    }

}
```

*Don´t forget to add permission to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```